# how can I disable output to log4j.rootLogger?

Tags: java, log4j

I want to disable the output to the console when logging to file. See config-file below:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L --- %m%n

log4j.category.FileLog=info,R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=E:\\temp\\FileLog
log4j.appender.R.Append = true
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%m[%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss}]%n
```

when I using:

```
Logger.getLogger("FileLog").info("LogText-FileLog");
```

this log print to `stdout` too,how can I disable it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `log4j.additivity.FileLog = false, that is the 'flag' you are looking for.

From the [official log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html):

> The output of a log statement of logger C will go to all the appenders
>   in C and its ancestors. This is the meaning of the term "appender
>   additivity".
>
> However, if an ancestor of logger C, say P, has the
>   additivity flag set to false, then C's output will be directed to all
>   the appenders in C and its ancestors upto and including P but not the
>   appenders in any of the ancestors of P.
>
> Loggers have their additivity flag set to true by default.

Removing "stdout" from your root logger (as proposed in other answers) might not be a solution, because I suppose you are still interested in that console logs in some cases.

Comment: thanks @Guido García, I tried `log4j.additivity.R = false` and `log4j.appender.R.additivity = false` ,but didn't works

Answer (score 6):

remove stdout from here

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,stdout
```

To:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to the exact question the user provided, but facing a similar problem with the following log4j code:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

I removed all logging lines from the console by changing

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

to

```
log4j.rootCategory=OFF, console
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove "stdout" from root logger. It will stop writing on the console.