# PHPUnit outputs every log message from both PHP' default error log as well as the custom application log file to the command line

Tags: php, xml, nginx, phpunit

When I run PHPUnit and it involves testing a class I wrote which either logs something via PHP' `error_log()` or via Monolog (to a custom file), the logged content is dumped on the command-line.

Even in its simplest form I can reproduce the issue. Not even sure if it is an issue, bottomline is that I want to turn off dumping of every logged item on the command-line. I've been banging my head against a wall for a while now but I can't seem to figure it out. How do I turn this off?

facts;

- every item I log is shown on the cli
- before running the test the following returns an empty string; `ini_get('error_log');`
- I'm on nginx (1.10.1) + php-fpm (using PHP 7.0.7)
- Related issue but not helpful; [Stop log messages from appearing in the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953527/stop-log-messages-from-appearing-in-the-command-line)

An example;

```
class OutputOnCliTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function assertAndLogSomething()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(true, true);

        error_log('I do not want to show this on the command line');
    }

    /** @test */
    public function assertAndLogSomethingElse()
    {
        $logger = new \Monolog\Logger('loggerName');

        // no need to set a Monolog handler for this example, just want to log right away
        $logger->info('I do not want to show this either');

        $this->assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

CLI:

```
$  ls -la

-rw-r--r--   1 user  group   1150 Dec  7 18:47 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x   4 user  group    136 Dec  7 17:44 tests
drwxr-xr-x  17 user  group    578 Dec  7 10:05 vendor


$  ./vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 5.7.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

I do not want to show this on the command line
.[2016-12-07 16:53:58] loggerName.INFO: I do not want to show this either
.                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 24 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
$
```

PHPUnit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit-Tests">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Can someone please help me out so I can stop banging my head. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more of a design solution but I'd mock the Logger object so it doesn't actually log anything, other than the logger test itself (but then if you are using Monolog like I do you don't need to test this anyway).

If you actually do want to test if output to the browser (or somewhere else) was received, you could try this:

```
/**
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 */
public function testOutputCanSend()
{
    ob_start();
    // Do some stuff here that outputs directly, $logger->addInfo() etc
    ob_end_clean();
}
```